# Finding Majority (leader) using an array implementation of a stack

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I'm trying to find the majority or leader, in a stack that isn't sorted, and i'm having trouble with my tos (top of stack variable). Below is my code with main included. The majority of an array or stack is any element which appears in the array more than half the time (arrSize/2).

```
public class findLeader {

 static class ArrayStack{
    private int[] stackArr;
    private int tos;//top of stack

    public ArrayStack(){
        stackArr = new int[10];
        tos = -1;
    }

    public ArrayStack(int size){
        stackArr = new int[size];
        tos = -1;
    }

    public ArrayStack(int[] arr, int tos){
        stackArr = arr;
        this.tos = tos;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
       return(tos == -1);
    }

    public int peek(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return -999;
        }
        return stackArr[tos];
    }

    public void push(int x){
        if(tos == stackArr.length - 1){
            return;
        }
        stackArr[++tos] = x;
    }

    public int pop(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return -999;
        }
        int popValue = stackArr[tos];
        stackArr[tos] = 0;
        --tos;
        return popValue;
    }

    public void print(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= tos; ++i){
            System.out.print(stackArr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static int leader(ArrayStack myStack){

    int initSize = myStack.tos + 1; //gets initial size of stack.
    int leader; //initialize leader or majority.

    while(!myStack.isEmpty()){
        leader = myStack.peek();//set first leader variable to the element at the tos.
        System.out.println("leader " + leader); //just for debugging
        System.out.println("tos " + myStack.tos); //debugging
        //System.out.println(isLeader(myStack, initSize, leader)); //debugging
        if(isLeader(myStack, initSize, leader)){      
          return 1;  
        }
        else{  
            myStack.pop();
        }
        System.out.println("after function tos " + myStack.tos); //debugging         
    }

    return -1;
}

public static boolean isLeader(ArrayStack myStack, int initSize, int leader){
    ArrayStack as = myStack;
    int count = 0;

    while(!as.isEmpty()){
        if(as.peek() == leader){
            as.pop();
            ++count;
        }
        else{
            as.pop();
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(count);
    if(count > initSize / 2)
        return true;
    else{  
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {2, 5, 6, 2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 2};

    ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack();

    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(6);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(8);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(5);

    System.out.println(leader(stack));

}
```

Where the problem arises is in the leader, and isLeader methods, after the initial call of isLeader, tos gets returned as tos = -1 as is demonstrated from my output below.

Output:

```
leader 5
tos 8
after function tos -1
-1
```

My intent is after every call to isLeader() if false is returned, i want to pop the tos variable from the top and call isLeader() once more with the new smaller stack.

Any help would really be appreciated, and I hope everyone is well!

Thank you

Comment: The problem appears to be that you pop all elements of your stack in `isLeader`. After the first call to `isLeader` your stack should be empty or at best half empty. You will need implement `isLeader` in a way that does not modify your stack.

Comment: Ahh I see, maybe if instead of popping the elements I just moved the tos down the stack, to keep the original stack in place.

Comment: This will probably break your stack as well as the `tos` is an attribute of the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally add a method `public Integer leader()` to your `ArrayStack` that returns the stack's leader or `null` if the stack has no leader:

```
public Integer leader() {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    final int neededLeaderCount = ((tos + 1) / 2) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= tos; ++i) {
        int currentElementCount = counts.getOrDefault(stackArr[i], 0) + 1;
        if (currentElementCount >= neededLeaderCount) {
            return stackArr[i];
        }
        counts.put(stackArr[i], currentElementCount);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your `isLeader` function could then be rewritten to:

```
public static boolean isLeader(ArrayStack myStack, int leader) {
    // use Objects.equals as myStack.leader() may be null
    return Objects.equals(myStack.leader(), leader);
}
```

This approach is much cleaner as it does not modify or require any internals of your `ArrayStack` outside of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by also tracking a currSize of the stack to pass to the isLeader function. I feel like i am complicating things, if anyone has a simpler solution and would like to share it, I would be open to it. Below is my code if anyone is interested.

```
public static int leader(ArrayStack myStack){
    int currSize = myStack.tos;
    int initSize = myStack.tos + 1; //gets initial size of stack.
    int leader; //initialize leader or majority.

    while(!myStack.isEmpty()){
        leader = myStack.peek();//set first leader variable to the element at the tos.
        System.out.println("leader " + leader); //just for debugging
        System.out.println("tos " + myStack.tos); //debugging
        //System.out.println(isLeader(myStack, initSize, leader)); //debugging
        if(isLeader(myStack, initSize, leader, currSize)){      
          return 1;  
        }
        else{
            --currSize;
            myStack.pop();
        }
        System.out.println("after function tos " + myStack.tos); //debugging         
    }

    return -1;
}

public static boolean isLeader(ArrayStack myStack, int initSize, int leader, int currSize){
    ArrayStack as = myStack;
    int count = 0;


    while(as.tos > -1){
        if(as.peek() == leader){
            --as.tos; //Just move tos pointer down stack rather than popping
                      //to maintain original stack.
            ++count;
        }
        else{
            --as.tos;
        }
    }

    if(count > initSize / 2)
        return true;
    else{
        as.tos = currSize;//reset the tos pointer back to the currSize of 
                          //stack.
        return false;
    }
}
```